# Swapping strings WITHOUT using double pointers

Tags: c, string

This is actually just a small part of the original assignment I have in algorithms and data structure. At some point I'm supposed to write a function that swaps two elements in an **array of strings**.

The prototype we **have to use** is:

```
void swap(char *a, char *b);
```

To me it makes much more sense passing double pointers to this function (if swapping strings). In fact, I don't know how to make their prototype work without using double pointers. Am I missing something or is this wrong?

I've done my research on this a while ago and there are many answered questions here, I'm just wondering whether the person who was designing this assignment made a mistake.

Comment: Two questions. Do we assume that the C-strings passed are the same length? And if not, are we supposed to assume they were allocated with `malloc()` and use `realloc()` to adjust their sizes as necessary, or should we know how much memory was allocated past the end of the null terminator? If so, we would probably benefit from a third argument indicating the amount of allocated bytes for each string.

Comment: You're right to query this. The assignment looks idiotic.

Comment: You can only use that `swap` function if `a` and `b` point to the same amount of memory (or an excessive amount of memory). E.g. `char s1[100] = "hello", s2[100] = "world"; swap(s1, s2)`

Comment: Have you been given sample code for the call site?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts There's no way to use `realloc` with that function prototype, because you can't change the caller's pointer, only the local copy of the pointer.

Comment: @user3386109 ah, you're right. Good point. Seems we have to make the assumption that enough memory is allocated at each pointer to contain either C-string

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I would agree with describing the assignment as questionable and am tempted to tick your comment. The phrasing is however just a little off.

Comment: The strings passed aren't the same length. They vary depending on the input.
I wasn't given sample code for the call site, that's why I can't really figure out what they had in mind.
I'll stick to double pointers.

Comment: They could (and probably do) define an array of strings as a 2D array of `char` like `char strings[500][32]` which would be 500 strings whose max length is 31.

Comment: The accepted answer conflicts with the problem statement "write a function that swaps two elements in an array of strings" ... swapping elements is not the same as swapping strings.

Comment: Given the prototype `void swap(char *a, char *b);`, you are not being passed "arrays of strings".  Assuming a "string" is a NUL-terminated sequence of `char`, an "array of strings" would be something like `char *array[]`.  @RamblinRose has it right. Whoever wrote this assignment needs to use the proper terminology.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: In fact there's no such thing as an "array of strings" in C. You can have an array of `char*` pointers (which might be pointers to strings), or you can have an array of `char[N]` arrays (each if which might contain a string). A "string" is not a data type in C.

Comment: I suggest avoiding the phrase "double pointer" to mean pointer-to-pointer. It also means `double*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can swap two strings by creating a temporary `char` array of length equal to either one of the two strings, and by using `strcpy()`.

Of course, you need to make sure that swapping does not overflow one of the two strings/arrays. Here is a sample example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    char *tmp = malloc(strlen(a) + 1);

    strcpy(tmp, a);
    strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, tmp);

    free(tmp);
}

int main(void)
{
    char str_a[50] = "Hello world";
    char str_b[50] = "What's up";

    swap(str_a, str_b);

    puts(str_a);
    puts(str_b);

    return 0;
}
```

Another approach is to use a loop with a single `char` variable, thus avoiding dynamic memory allocation:

```
void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    char tmp;

    while (*a && *b)
    {
        tmp = *a;
        *a++ = *b;
        *b++ = tmp;
    }

    if (!*a)
    {
        size_t n = 0;
        while (b[n])
        {
            *a++ = b[n++];
        }
    }
    else if (!*b)
    {
        size_t n = 0;
        while (a[n])
        {
            *b++ = a[n++];
        }
    }
    *a = '\0';
    *b = '\0';
}
```

Comment: @melpomene Because I use visual studio :)

Comment: That makes no sense. Do you mean you have it configured to use C++?

Comment: You only need one `char` of scratch space. You don't really need to `malloc` a whole string.

Comment: @melpomene Yes. The C compiler inside visual studio is very old, and disgusting.

Comment: @melpomene Do you mean, I can simply create a `char` variable, and use it in a loop to swap one character at a time?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. (Long answer: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees.)